# How do I cite these sources?

Tags: citations

https://documents.deathpenaltyinfo.org/Lucio-TCCA-Stay-Order-2022-04-25.pdf
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cf5pWQL27NQCiC-oDtyuXJi-RnSFl8Qz/view

I need these sources to be cited for a paper but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: What citation style (or style guide)? Where are you struggling exactly with creating the citations? You need to make sure all the information needed to help you is in the post itself (and not behind links or missing entirely).

Answer (score 1):

Legal sources often have very specific information that you need to cite; it varies from country to country and whether you're citing in APA, MLA, Chicago, or another citation method. I'm not an expert in legal citation.

However, APA 7th edition provides the following citation for a U.S. district court case:

Burriola v. Greater Toledo YMCA, 133 F. Supp. 2d 1034 (N.D. Ohio 2001). https://law.justia.com/federal/district-courts/FSupp2/133/1034/2293141/

Only use URLs that are retrievable by strangers, to be certain that they can retrieve the works you cite. It's also best if the URL leads the reader to the original source where you first found the document.